# How to format a cell to change color on a future date

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format a cell in google sheets to change colors when it reaches a certain date.

For example, if I call a customer on 10/10/2021, I want to format a cell in the row to turn red on 10/20/2021 so I know it's time to follow up.

I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Control + ;** or **⌘;** keyboard shortcut to insert the current date in a cell in some column. Then select the whole column and choose:

**Format > Conditional formatting > Less than or equal to >** `=today() - 10`

See [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) and [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) for more info.